# How can I turn other cells red based on another cells data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the cells in column D turning red if the date entered is either today's date, or within the next 7 days. I also need the cells in columns G-J to turn red if the dates entered into the cells in column D are either today's date, or within the next 7 days, but I can't figure it out. Even if I could just get the cells in column G-J to turn red if the corresponding cell in column D is red, that would work also. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

** Update: I changed the CF to include $F$8:$J$981 but now the cells that don't have a date entered are red also. That is my fault for not mentioning that in the beginning... I need the cells without a date to remain without color, until the date is entered & then to be red only if the date is of today's or the next 7 days. Here is an image of what I have now:

image-=$D8

Answer (score 0):

In the formula, please use relative references (without the $ in front) instead of absolute references (with the $ in front).

1. Ensure the active cell is D2.  (That is where I started)
2. Open up the conditional formatting tab.
3. Select the formula you want to adjust and remove the `$` in front of the row `2`.  Keep the `$` in front of the column `D`.
4. Click OK
5. In the previous dialog box, in the Applies To section. type D2:J14 (this is my example)

   [image: Conditional Formatting Picture]

Comment: You are right.  $D$2:$D$14, $G$2:$J$14

Comment: It worked, kind of... The cells that don't have a date are now red also. Is there away to leave those blank until a date is entered & only turn red if the date is today's date or the next 7? I will post a picture in my original post to show you. I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that to begin with, that is my fault.

Comment: =(AND(ISDATE($D2), $D2<TODAY()+7))   Place that in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

This response will depend on how you applied the initial conditional formatting rule. You've offered very little in the way of specifics.

You just need to change the *Applies to:* range to include columns G:J.

Select the same range you selected when creating the CFR initially. Choose Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting, Manage Rules.

Find the rule that turns dates within 7 days and change the *Applies to:* range to include columns G:J. For example:

```
'if you have
D:D
'change to
D:D, G:J

'if you have
D2:D100
'change to
D2:D100, G2:J100
```

If your CFR is based on a formula or cell address, you need to lock the column as absolute.

```
'if you have a formula like
=and(D2>=today(), D2<=today()+7)

'change to
=and($D2>=today(), $D2<=today()+7)
```

Click OK to apply your changes.